# PHP Split Search Bar Keywords By Spaces

Tags: php, mysql, url, search, keyword

OK let me be as specific as possible.... I would like to change the way my search bar behaves.  Right now the string has to match the MySQL query exactly!!! or it won't show my products.

Here is what I got:
A search for "case iphone"

```
searchitems.php?tosearch=case+iphone&Search=Search
```

[image]

Now a search for "iphone case"

```
searchitems.php?tosearch=iphone+case&Search=Search
```

[image]

Now based on how the query would work...if I type in the URL manually to this... it works how I want it to:

```
searchitems.php?tosearch=%iphone%&%case%&Search=Search
```

[image]

So how do I go about changing the URL from

```
searchitems.php?tosearch=case+iphone&Search=Search
```

to

```
searchitems.php?tosearch=%iphone%&%case%&Search=Search
```

Here is the code that I have so far:

Search Form In index.php

```
<form method="GET" action="searchitems.php">
    <input size="50" type="text" name="tosearch" value="Search" name="keyword" id="keyword" title="keyword" onfocus="clearText(this)" onblur="clearText(this)" class="txt_field">
    <input type="submit" name="Search" value="Search" alt="Search" id="searchbutton" title="Search" class="sub_btn">
</form>
```

searchitems.php (Sorry if it isn't tabbed correctly just copied and pasted)

```
<?php
include('core/header2.php');
include ('core/connectdb.php');
if(isset($_GET['tosearch'])) {
$tosearch=$_GET['tosearch'];
$tosearch=urldecode($tosearch);
$tosearch = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', trim($tosearch));
$search_terms = explode(' ',$tosearch);
$search_terms[] = $tosearch;
$search_terms=array_unique($search_terms);
$query = "select * from products where ";
$query_fields = Array();
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM products"; 
$columnlist = $connect->query($sql); 
while($arr = $columnlist->fetch_assoc()){ 
  extract($arr);
  $query_fields[] = $Field . " LIKE ('%". $tosearch . "%')";
}
$query .= implode(" OR ", $query_fields);
                $results = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysql_error());
                $rows = $results->num_rows;
                if ($rows > 0) {
                    $cols = 5;
                    $counter = 1;
                    $nbsp = $cols - ($rows % $cols);
                    echo '<div id="content" class="float_r">';
                    echo "<table border=\"0\">";
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                        if(($counter % $cols) == 1) {    // Check if it's new row
                            echo '<tr align="center">'; 
                        }
                        extract($row);
                        echo '<td  valign="top" style="padding-right:15px;">';
                        echo "<a href=itemdetails.php?itemcode=$item_code>";
                        echo '<img src=' . $imagename . ' style="max-width:120px;max-height:140px;
                        width:auto;height:auto;"></img><br/>';
                        echo $item_name .'<br/>';
                        echo "</a>";
                        echo '<div class="product_price">$'. $price .'</div>';
                        echo "<form method=\"POST\" action=\"cart.php?action=add&icode=$item_code&iname=$item_name&iprice=$price&ilocation=$location\">";
                        echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"addtocart\" value=\"Add To Cart\"></form>";
                        echo "</td>";
                        if(($counter % $cols) == 0 ){
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                        $counter++;
                    }
                    if($nbsp > 0) { // Add unused column in last row
                        for ($i = 0; $i < $nbsp; $i++)  { 
                            echo '<td>&nbsp;</td>';     
                        }
                        echo '</tr>';
                    }

                                }
}
echo '</table></div><div class="cleaner"></div>';
include('core/footer.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, brother, it's a bad approach how you doing it. But for learning, its fine. For `+` sign issue, you can use php `urldecode`, example:

```
<?php 
$tosearch = 'a+b';
echo urldecode($tosearch);
```

it has its own pro/con thing but on high-level it will work for you, you can dig more into it if you like.

Comment: The + sign is simply because the $tosearch variable already has spaces in them the urldecode(); just takes out any + characters...that doesn't solve my problem on how to replace the spaces and enter this into my url %item%&%name%.

Comment: Why would you need '%' sign in the search term? I have created a gist and running sample code for you. Have a look.
https://gist.github.com/mszb/d2b6fd566ed5e390e98bf419bcd944ec -- http://main.xfiddle.com/code_33641226.php?s=iphone+case

Comment: I've updated my search code to work with what you have provided...unfortunately it is still giving me the same results when I search for "case iphone" I get the one result, but "iphone case" no results.  I need my search to separate both keywords so it searches for any result with "case" and any result with "iphone".  Putting %iphone%&%case% in the url works like I want it to.

Comment: there you go... i've updated the gist...... https://gist.github.com/mszb/d2b6fd566ed5e390e98bf419bcd944ec

Comment: I've added the new code into it...still getting the same issue...let me change my code up above for you to see it...

Comment: you also need to update your while loop to iterate search terms. like: `while($arr = $columnlist->fetch_assoc()){ 
  extract($arr);
  foreach($search_terms as $search_term){
        $query_fields[] = $Field . " LIKE ('%". $search_term . "%')";
    }
}`

Comment: Ahh victorious!!! lol Thank you so much Shoaib for your help...I wish I did know more about these things, but as you say...I am just starting out and this just gets me a step closer to where I need to be...maybe later on down the road I can use this information you have given to me in order to figure out how other search engines are done. But for now...this is what I needed :)